# Visual Basic - Web browser load URLs from text

Tags: vb.net

i am not so great with Visual basic, but i need some help on creating a web browser that would load several links import from a text file, and for the web browser to navigate to them. This is what i have so far

```
 Dim link As String = OpenFileDialog2.FileName 
            Dim links As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(link)
            MsgBox(links)
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(links)
```

You help means a lot. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The WebBrowser Control either will show the webpage in the Control which will limit you to one page, or you can tell it to open the pages in separate windows which will open an Internet Explorer window for each link. I also used the File.ReadAllLines Method in order to get an array of the Links so that you can iterate through the Web Pages . This works for me but might not be what you are wanting.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim wb As New WebBrowser

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filename As String = "C:\temp\links.txt"
        Dim links As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
        For Each link As String In links
            wb.Navigate(link, True)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        Controls.Add(wb)
        wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

   End Sub

End Class
```

My text file called Links.txt looks like this:

> www.google.com
>   www.msdn.com
>   www.bing.com